# search text not working for listview ie

Tags: listview, search

**addTextChangedlistener** returning error, Pls help. i have Addportfolio.java file loading list dialog from another xml for listview. listview xml has search text and listview field

AddPortfolio.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class AddPortfolio extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    ListView list;
    Dialog listDialog;
    DBAdapter myDb;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList nameList = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<String> array_search= new ArrayList<String>();
    int textlength=0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_portfolio);

    myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDb.open();
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // Process the data:
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            nameList.add(name);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // Close the cursor to avoid a resource leak.
    cursor.close();
}
  public void addlist(View v){
showdialog();
   }
  private void showdialog()
   {

listDialog = new Dialog(AddPortfolio.this);
listDialog.setTitle("Select Company");
 LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View v = li.inflate(R.layout.listviewdisplay, null, false);
 listDialog.setContentView(v);
 listDialog.setCancelable(true);
 //there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!

  list = (ListView) listDialog.findViewById(R.id.listview);
 list.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this);
 //list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList));
 //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it

 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList);
 list.setAdapter(adapter); 
 listDialog.show();


 EditText st= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 st.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        AddPortfolio.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

      }

     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
             int arg3) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.i("REACHES BEFORE", "YES");   
     }

     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
     }
 }); 
 }


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
    {
EditText edittext1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_company);
    edittext1.setText((CharSequence) nameList.get(arg2));
    listDialog.cancel();   
    }
    }
```

Logcat Error

```
   02-19 02:24:26.484: D/AndroidRuntime(1487): Shutting down VM
```

`02-19 02:24:26.484: D/AndroidRuntime(1487): Shutting down VM
02-19 02:24:26.484: W/dalvikvm(1487): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3afeba8)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): Process: com.example.merostock, PID: 1487
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     ... 11 more
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.example.merostock.AddPortfolio.showdialog(AddPortfolio.java:77)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.example.merostock.AddPortfolio.addlist(AddPortfolio.java:53)
02-19 02:24:26.584: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     ... 14 more`

Answer (score 0):

please check line 77 in AddPortfolio.java, it causes NPE

Comment: i have this code in line 77 :    EditText st= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  st.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

Comment: do you have EditText with id editText1 in your layout add_portfolio? Maybe the EditText is in your dialog layout.

Comment: i have editText1 in dialog layout ie listviewdisplay.xml. which is called in  LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View v = li.inflate(R.layout.listviewdisplay, null, false);

Comment: EditText st= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); this line means that you findViewById in activity content view, not dialog view, you don't have it, so NPE causes. try this: EditText st= (EditText) listDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

Comment: it worked, but got another problem now, when i search in the field, it shows same company twice in listview and when i select it returns from the original listview index

Comment: can you post the filter() method in this line: AddPortfolio.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

Comment: i have inserted same code. db had double entry that i corrected. but after selection it is returning result from original listview index not after search result selection

Comment: you get content from original list not adapter: edittext1.setText((CharSequence) nameList.get(arg2));

Comment: so, how to set text from search filter

Comment: you search all your result in DB, at first, you can store data in a List like what you have done but please move it to your adapter, then use another List to store the data what you want to present. BTW, do not query DB in your main thread, it will block your application.

Comment: If this helps you, pls check it as answer.

Comment: hi, one more question, if i want to update value automatically after 24hrs, how can i do it. btw i did search text with String and it worked.  a = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
  edittext1.setText(a);

Comment: updating value automatically after 24hrs is a schedule task, you can use Handler or system alarm service.